# ERROR [Error: undefined Unable to resolve module util from node_modules/uuidv4/build/lib/uuidv4.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

```
 ERROR  [Error: undefined Unable to resolve module util from /Users/mac2015/Desktop/Projects/mobile/Ejob/node_modules/uuidv4/build/lib/uuidv4.js: util could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  2 | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  3 | exports.jsonSchema = exports.fromString = exports.empty = exports.isUuid = exports.regex = exports.uuid = void 0;
> 4 | const util_1 = require("util");
    |                         ^
  5 | const uuid_1 = require("uuid");
  6 | const regex = {
  7 |     v4: /(?:^[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}$)|(?:^0{8}-0{4}-0{4}-0{4}-0{12}$)/u,]
```

I've installed uuidv4 in my react native application, after import it from uuidv4, i'm trying to use as id for my items but i'm getting this error.

Comment: Try to install `util` seperatly.

Comment: thanks it works after running npm install util and uuidv4

Also import uuid from "uuidv4" instead of import { uuid } from 'uuidv4';